# undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.layerAdd') issue coming on safari but working fine on chrome

Tags: javascript, safari, leaflet, issue-tracking

[image]

leaflet issue coming on safari but properly working on chrome.

I don't know what to do here so please help?

Here is my code:

[image: code]

Here is the Leaflet library error

[image: code]

Comment: Show your code please, we cannot guess it.

Comment: added please check now

Comment: I would add `console.log(overlays);` before the line 768

Comment: got an array in console but nothing like mode in array